# Check FTP connection successful or not in Mule anypoint?

Tags: ftp, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

Can anybody tell me how to verify that whether sftp:outbound-endpoint connection got successfully or not at mule level itself(in mule-config.xml).

Is there any parameter/attribute for ftp outbound-endpoint which tells connection got successfully or not in mule anypoint?

I am creating a file and deploying that file to ftp sever using ftp outbound-endpoint.
So i want to verify at mule level itself whether file has been transferred successfully or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Mule should throw an exception in case of any issue. You should have exception handling strategy to handle failures rather than verifying success.

For exception handling refer [this blog](https://www.ricston.com/blog/catching-sftps-connection-failure-exceptions/).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this info in mule log file, once you run the scenario.